# Do Not Crawl certain page in a particular link(exclude certain url from crawling)

Tags: java, web-crawler

This is the below code in my MyCrawler.java and it is crawling all those links that I have provided in `href.startsWith` but suppose If I do not want to crawl this particular page `http://inv.somehost.com/people/index.html` then how can I do this in my code..

```
public MyCrawler() {
    }

    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {

        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();


    if (href.startsWith("http://www.somehost.com/") || href.startsWith("http://inv.somehost.com/") || href.startsWith("http://jo.somehost.com/")) {
//And If I do not want to crawl this page http://inv.somehost.com/data/index.html then how it can be done..


                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }


    public void visit(Page page) {

        int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();

        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
        String text = page.getText();
        List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();
        int parentDocid = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();

        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            System.out.println("URL:- " +url1);
            URLConnection connection = url1.openConnection();

            Map responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
            Iterator iterator = responseMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String key = iterator.next().toString();

                if (key.contains("text/html") || key.contains("text/xhtml"))
                {
                    System.out.println(key);
                    // Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
                    if (filters.matcher(key) != null){
                        System.out.println(url1);
                        try {
                            final File parentDir = new File("crawl_html");
                            parentDir.mkdir();
                            final String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(url1.toString());
                            final String fileName = hash + ".txt";
                            final File file = new File(parentDir, fileName);
                            boolean success =file.createNewFile(); // Creates file crawl_html/abc.txt


                             System.out.println("hash:-"  + hash);

                                    System.out.println(file);
                            // Create file if it does not exist



                                // File did not exist and was created
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

                                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

                                // Also could be written as follows on one line
                                // Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[0]));

                                            // Write text to file
                                Tika t = new Tika();
                                String content= t.parseToString(new URL(url1.toString()));


                                out.println("===============================================================");
                                out.println(url1);
                                out.println(key);
                                //out.println(success);
                                out.println(content);

                                out.println("===============================================================");
                                out.close();
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();



                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (TikaException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        // http://google.com
                    }
                }


            }



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        System.out.println("=============");
    }
```

And this is my Controller.java code from where MyCrawler is getting called..

```
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            CrawlController controller = new CrawlController("/data/crawl/root");
            controller.addSeed("http://www.somehost.com/");
            controller.addSeed("http://inv.somehost.com/");
            controller.addSeed("http://jo.somehost.com/");
            controller.start(MyCrawler.class, 20);  
            controller.setPolitenessDelay(200);
            controller.setMaximumCrawlDepth(2);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a property to tell which urls you want to exclude.

Add to your exclusions list all the pages that you don't want them to get crawled.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {


        List<Pattern> exclusionsPatterns;

        public MyCrawler() {
            exclusionsPatterns = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
            //Add here all your exclusions using Regular Expresssions
            exclusionsPatterns.add(Pattern.compile("http://investor\\.somehost\\.com.*"));
        }

        /*
         * You should implement this function to specify
         * whether the given URL should be visited or not.
         */
        public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
                String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();

                //Iterate the patterns to find if the url is excluded.
               for (Pattern exclusionPattern : exclusionsPatterns) {
                   Matcher matcher = exclusionPattern.matcher(href);
                   if (matcher.matches()) {
                      return false;
                   }
               }

                if (href.startsWith("http://www.ics.uci.edu/")) {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
}
```

In this example we are telling that all urls that start with `http://investor.somehost.com` should not be crawled.

So these wont be crawled:

```
http://investor.somehost.com/index.html
http://investor.somehost.com/something/else
```

I recommend you reading about [regular expresions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

Comment: So how can we do this.. that's what I am asking..Any idea??

Comment: You could do this by using a List<String> exclusions; and add to it the urls that you want to exclude. You will need to check that list to decide if a page should be processed.

Comment: Any example with my code will be appreciated.. And is should be done where in my MyCrawler.java file..

Comment: thanks for the answer.. Its working... :) Can you give some suggestions on this one.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683764/increase-number-of-threads-in-crawler)

Comment: I think it is crawling that link also... I don't know why... I checked that..As I don't want to crawl anything that starts with `http://investor.somehost.com`