# Increase number of threads in crawler

Tags: java, web-crawler

```
This is the code taken from http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/ and the name of this file is MyCrawler.java


public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {

        Pattern filters = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|bmp|gif|jpe?g"
                + "|png|tiff?|mid|mp2|mp3|mp4"
                + "|wav|avi|mov|mpeg|ram|m4v|pdf"
                + "|rm|smil|wmv|swf|wma|zip|rar|gz))$");

        /*
         * You should implement this function to specify
         * whether the given URL should be visited or not.
         */
        public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
                String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
                if (filters.matcher(href).matches()) {
                        return false;
                }
                if (href.startsWith("http://www.xyz.us.edu/")) {
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

        /*
         * This function is called when a page is fetched
         * and ready to be processed by your program
         */
        public void visit(Page page) {
                int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();
                String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
                String text = page.getText();
                List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();            
        }
}
```

And this is the code for Controller.java from where MyCrawler is getting called..

```
public class Controller {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                CrawlController controller = new CrawlController("/data/crawl/root");
                controller.addSeed("http://www.xyz.us.edu/");
                controller.start(MyCrawler.class, 10);  
        }
}
```

So I just want to make sure what does this line means in controller.java file

```
controller.start(MyCrawler.class, 10);
```

here what is the meaning of 10.. And if we Increase this 10 to 20 then what will be the effect... Any suggestions will be appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/trunk/crawler4j/src/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.java?r=6) website shows the source for CrawlController.

Incrementing from 10 to 20 increases the number of crawlers (each in their own thread) - studying that code will tell you what affect this will have.

Answer (score 2):

Given the name you put on the post, you appear to already know what this does - it sets the number of crawler threads.  As for what effect it will have... that depends largely on how much of the time each thread will be waiting for I/O - mostly network, and a little disk, and on how much CPU and disk throughput you have.  Peak throughput will happen when one of these happens:

- no more CPU time left
- no more network bandwidth
- no more disk bandwidth

For CPU, don't expect to get to 100% - figure 80% or so max.